# Making the Document Root dynamic

Tags: .htaccess, document, root

I have been searching and looking for the answer to this for SO long now without any joy, I hope someone can help.

Okay I have a web structure of:

Main folder - This is where you first land prior to logging in. After you log in you will be either directed to a number of websites that are resident in a sub-folder called websites. The problem I have is that I would like the document root, say the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable, to default to the root of the website folder that it has been directed to. You see I have a lot of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in my php code and I use the '/' slash a lot in the href on my HTML tags.

I have seen that I could accomplish this by adding a .htaccess in the root of eiach website folder but 1, would like work for my situation and 2, could anyone please help me with the code. I understand I can use the RewriteRule command but I can't get my head around it. My folder stricture is like this:

login (index.html)

websites folder

website1 (index.html)

website2 (index.html)

website3 (index.html)

I have tried many versions of using RewriteCond etc but non of them work.

If anyone can help me out here I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do in your htaccess file that's going to be able to change the document root. One thing that you can do is create separate domains that you can make their document roots point to each of the websites folders. Then proxy to one of those domains.

That way the URL on the browser doesn't change domain names, and internally, you're proxying requests back to yourself and the individual website domains will each have their own document root.